# Using EXISTS in SQL ignores selected columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

```
SELECT st.state_id, 
       st.state_name, 
       st.country_id 
FROM   state_table st 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 0 / 0 
               FROM   country c 
               WHERE  st.country_id = c.country_id 
                      AND c.country_name = 'India')
```

This query produces the expected output matching `st.country_id = c.country_id`. In this query however, `0 / 0`, in the inner subquery is expected to be replaced by `c.country_id`.

The equivalent `IN()` query would look like the following.

```
SELECT st.state_id, 
       st.state_name, 
       st.country_id
FROM   state_table st
WHERE  country_id IN(SELECT c.country_id 
                     FROM   country c
                     WHERE  c.country_name = 'India')
```

It appears that the list of columns in the `select` clause inside `EXISTS()` subquery is ignored. Is this true?

Comment: Yes. All that matters is whether the sub-select finds any rows.

Comment: I recommend using a `JOIN` rather than `EXISTS` or `IN`.

Comment: @user2864740 - use SELECT 1, this makes the the select simpler and no more than one row/column needs to be constructed to establish TRUE, and even better user JOIN as Barmar suggests - it's oodles faster.

Comment: @Barmar: Recent versions of MySQL handle `IN`-style semijoins properly. And anyway, in this case the subquery presumably returns just one row in most cases.

Comment: @PreetSangha Ooh, okay. That's gonna be my *new* way for EXISTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It appears that the list of columns in the `select` clause inside `EXISTS()` subquery is ignored. Is this true?

Yup! All that matters is how many rows it returns.

(Actually, it wouldn't surprise me if some DBMSes do at least *evaluate* the field-list, even though the values themselves are discarded. So `0 / 0` may not be portable.)

**Addendum:** I just tested using sqlfiddle.com, and it appears that MySQL treats `0 / 0` as `NULL` rather than an error, so that doesn't signify; but even on DMBSes such as Oracle that normally *do* treat `0 / 0` as an error, the predicate `EXISTS (SELECT 0 / 0 ...)` was successful. So, maybe it *is* portable? (Granted, I only tested a handful of DBMSes — one version each of MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and SQL Server — so I can't make a guarantee.)

Comment: @Phil: I'm pretty sure it *would*. It certainly does in at least some DBMSes. Why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: Many years spent on Oracle + gut feeling I guess :)

Comment: @Phil: Using sqlfiddle.com, I've just tried `SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1) t WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL);` on MySQL 5.5.23, `SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM dual);` on Oracle 11gR2, and `SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL);` on PostgreSQL 9.3.1 and MS SQL Server 2012. In all cases, it successfully returned a single row containing `1`. I guess your gut feeling was mistaken. (Don't feel bad for having it -- gut feelings about dark corners are often wrong, because our ordinary experience is in avoiding them -- but next time, be sure to test it!)

Comment: Nicely proven. I stand corrected and learnt something in the process :D

Comment: @Phil: [*MySQL: EXISTS - NOT EXISTS*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: @Ravinder I was more concerned with ruakh's comment about portability. I know what the MySQL docs say

Comment: @Phil: I got it. I just included `MySQL` as the link is pointing to MySQL documentation. The similar docs are available on [`Oracle`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), [`T-SQL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx),

Answer (score 2):

> *It appears that the list of columns in the select clause inside EXISTS() subquery is ignored. Is this true?*

Yes, it is.

As per documentation on [***`EXISTS` - `NOT EXISTS`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

> `SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2);`
>   Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with `SELECT *`, but it could begin with
>   `SELECT 5` or `SELECT column1` or anything at all. MySQL ignores the
>   `SELECT list` in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.
>
> For the preceding example, if t2 contains any rows, even rows with
>   nothing but NULL values, the `EXISTS` condition is TRUE. This is
>   actually an unlikely example because a `[NOT] EXISTS` subquery almost
>   always contains correlations.

Some of references to other DBMS's that explain the same are listed below:

1. [***Oracle: Exists and Not Exists with SubQueries***](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
2. [***T-SQL Exists***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)
3. [***PostgreSQL: Exists***](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html)